# How to not apply instance constraints on a restricted function which uses a more generic function?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Let's say I have a function:

```hs
logResult :: (MonadIO m, ToJSON a) => Either MyError (Response a) -> m ()
logResult = ...
```

In this function, if I get:

1. `Right (Response a)` - I call `toJSON` to log the result.
2. `Left MyError` - I log it as well. `MyError` already has a `ToJSON` instance defined.

Now I want to write a helper function:

```hs
logError :: (MonadIO m) :: MyError -> m ()
logError err = logResult (Left err)
```

But GHC complains something along the following lines:

```
    • Could not deduce (ToJSON a0) arising from a use of ‘logResult’                                                                    
      from the context: MonadIO m                                                                                                       
        bound by the type signature for:                                                                                                
                   logError :: forall (m :: * -> *).                                                                                    
                               MonadIO m =>                                                                                             
                               L.Logger                                                                                                 
                               -> Wai.Request
                               -> MyError
                               -> m ()

...
...
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
```

I understand the error is because `logResult` needs to guarantee that the `a` in `Response a` must have a `ToJSON` instance defined. But in `logError` I am explicitly passing `Left MyError`. Shouldn't this disambiguate ?

Is there any way I can write the `logError` helper function ?

PS: I have simplified the type signatures in the example. The error message has the gory details.

Comment: I also couldn't phrase the title correctly. Which shows my lack of understanding of the concept/idea, I guess.

Comment: Why do you use `Left` here, shouldn't you ure `logError = logResult`? In fact it makes more sense to write it like `logError MonadIO m :: Either MyError a -> m()` that thus unpacks it, and in case of a `Left` logs the error, and otherwise does not do anything.

Comment: At first sight it looks like you defined `logError` in a `where` clause? In that case, it is likely a result of the [monomorphic restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction).

Comment: No. I already have `logResult` for that. I need `logError` in case where I want to use `either logError return result`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `logError` is not defined in a where clause. Should I post more code details?

Comment: ah, I got it, by using `Left err`, you know that the type is `Either MyError a`, but what `a` is, is unclear. You could perhaps solve it, by forcing a type for which you know a `ToJSON` exists, like: `logError err = logResult (Left err :: Either MyError Int)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah Thanks! That worked! It sure looks hacky though. Is there any extension that enables this sort of thing?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Also, how can I phrase my title better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why is this one function? If the behavior of this function splits so cleanly into two, then it should *be* two functions. That is, you've written one monolithic function and are trying to define a simpler function as a utility using it. Instead, write a simple function and write the monolithic function as a composition of it with another. The type is pretty much asking for it: `Either a b -> c` is isomorphic to `(a -> c, b -> c)`.

```
-- you may need to factor out some common utility stuff, too
logError :: (MonadIO m) :: MyError -> m ()
logResponse :: (MonadIO m, ToJSON a) => Response a -> m ()

logResult :: (MonadIO m, ToJSON a) => Either MyError (Response a) -> m ()
logResult = either logError logResponse
```

`logResult` still has its uses; if you get an `Either MyError (Response a)` from some library, then `logResult` can deal with it without much fuss. But, otherwise, you shouldn't be writing `logResult (Left _)` or `logResult (Right _)` very often; that essentially treats `logResult . Left` and `logResult . Right` as their own functions, which leads you back to actually writing them as separate functions.

> But in `logError` I am explicitly passing `Left MyError`. Shouldn't this disambiguate?

No, it shouldn't. The end and beginning of the issue is that `logResult` looks like this:

```
logResult :: (MonadIO m, ToJSON a) => Either MyError (Response a) -> m ()
```

When you call it, the implementation doesn't matter one lick. The type says you need `ToJSON a`—you need to provide `ToJSON a`. That's it. If you know that you don't need `ToJSON a` for `Left` values, then you possess useful information that is not reflected in the type. You should add that information to the type, which, in this case, means splitting it into two. It would (IMO) actually be bad language design to allow what you were thinking of, because the halting problem should make it impossible to do correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I understand it now. Splitting it into two functions make sense.